# Pie Chart tooltip thousand seperator and rtl labels doesn't work in highchart

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I'm using highchart in my web site. I wanna use thousand seperator in tooltip.
Here's the code:

```
divChart.highcharts({
                lang: {
                    thousandsSep: ','
                },
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    headerFormat: '<div style="direction:rtl; text-align:center; font-size:16px;">{point.key}</div><table >',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="text-align: center;color:{series.color};width:100px;"><b style="margin:4px;">{point.y:,.0f}</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>'
                },
                series: temp
            });
```

But it's not working.
And also I wanna display pie chart labels in rtl direction.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tooltip formatter and inside use a [Highcharts.numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat)

```
tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<div style="direction:rtl; text-align:center; font-size:16px;">'+this.key+'</div><table><tr><td style="text-align: center;color:'+this.series.color+';width:100px;"><b style="margin:4px;">'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0,'.',',')+'</b></td></tr></table>';
        }
    },
```

Example: 
- http://jsfiddle.net/bd1hvj1y/